# Ray Dataset loading HDFS: Failed to close HdfsReadableFile: IOError: HDFS CloseFile failed. Detail: [errno 255] Unknown error 255

Tags: python, java, hadoop, hdfs, ray

I am using [Ray Dataset read parquets](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/data/api/doc/ray.data.read_parquet.html) on the HDFS cluster.

```py
import ray
test_dataset = ray.data.read_parquet('hdfs://hadoop@192.168.222.236:9000/path/to/file.parquet')
test_dataset.take(1)
```

When reading parquets, Ray cluster throws the following error messages:

```
(_sample_fragment pid=111158) FSDataInputStream#close error:
(_sample_fragment pid=111158) IOException: Filesystem closedjava.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
(_sample_fragment pid=111158) /arrow/cpp/src/arrow/status.cc:155: Failed to close HdfsReadableFile: IOError: HDFS CloseFile failed. Detail: [errno 255] Unknown error 255
(_sample_fragment pid=111158)   at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181) [repeated 3x across cluster]
(_sample_fragment pid=81082, ip=192.168.222.237) FSDataInputStream#close error:
(_sample_fragment pid=81082, ip=192.168.222.237) IOException: Filesystem closedjava.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
(_sample_fragment pid=81082, ip=192.168.222.237) /arrow/cpp/src/arrow/status.cc:155: Failed to close HdfsReadableFile: IOError: HDFS CloseFile failed. Detail: [errno 255] Unknown error 255
(_sample_fragment pid=81082, ip=192.168.222.237)        at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180) [repeated 3x across cluster]
(_sample_fragment pid=8274, ip=192.168.222.236) FSDataInputStream#close error:
(_sample_fragment pid=8274, ip=192.168.222.236) IOException: Filesystem closedjava.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
(_sample_fragment pid=8274, ip=192.168.222.236) /arrow/cpp/src/arrow/status.cc:155: Failed to close HdfsReadableFile: IOError: HDFS CloseFile failed. Detail: [errno 255] Unknown error 255
(_sample_fragment pid=8274, ip=192.168.222.236)         at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181) [repeated 3x across cluster]
```

I treated it as a warning since the data are successfully loaded while the cluster keeps spamming this.
Even though this is not blocking the usage, I still want to find out why.

There is an interesting thing that the messages show some failed at `java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)` and some are at `java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)` (without `java.base`).

The Ray workers' machines are the same as the Hadoop workers' machines.

The `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set. The Hadoop Namenode information page shows quite normal.

#### Environments

Python 3.8.13

```
ray                               2.8.1
pyarrow                           14.0.0
```

Hadoop 3.3.6

Java

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-8u372-ga~us1-0ubuntu1~18.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b09, mixed mode)
```

OS

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

---

I have checked the Ray cluster and Hadoop cluster status, and both are normal.
The returned dataset can successfully train the model.

What I expect is to somehow get rid of these messages by solving the root cause. If the data is successfully loaded, this is quite weird, and I worry may or may not the program will crash or the result will not be trustworthy.